# Nested Json to CSV powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv, nested

I tried to solve it on my own but my knowlegde of PS and Json is just not so good that I can adapt other Solutions to my Problem.

The Tasks seems quite simple, but my json Structure which I get through a Rest API is kinda stupid for me.

Example JSON (which has more columns like (test-id,test-Name) but excatly the same logic over all columns in Fields):

```
     {
  "entities": [
    {
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Name": "test-id",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "1851"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "test-name",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "01_DUMMY"
            }
          ]
        }


      ],
      "Type": "run",
      "children-count": 0
    },
    {
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Name": "test-id",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "1852"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "test-name",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "02_DUMMY"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Type": "run",
      "children-count": 0
    }
  ],
  "TotalResults": 2
}
```

I tried to following PS Script:

```
Get-Content $file -raw |
convertfrom-json  | select -ExpandProperty entities |
select -ExpandProperty Fields |
select -ExpandProperty Values |
Export-CSV $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

But my CSV Result Looks like this:

```
"value"
"1851"
"01_DUMMY"
"N"
```

I would like to receive following result:

```
test-id,test-Name,run,children-count
1851,01_DUMMY,run,0
1852,02_DUMMY,run,0
```

Comment: Your posted json isn't valid, so this is not a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for noticing, tried to simplify my example. Now the Json is valid again.